# How to replace numbers by correct value (string)?

Tags: r, replace, gsub

I'm trying to replace some numbers (from 1 to 15) with a string value but it's not doing it correctly. Here's my code :

```
before = c("1","11","2","22")

after = c("A","B","c","E")

phrase = list( c("1","11") , c("2","22") )


for (i in phrase){
 
  r =  stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(
    
    i , 
    
    before, 
    
    after, 
    
    vectorize_all = FALSE)
  
  print(r)
  
}
```

here's what I'm getting

```
[1] "A"  "AA"
[1] "c"  "cc"
```

how do I correct this?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: Those aren't numbers.  Those are numerals in a string.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regular expressions since you are doing full text matching. You can create a look up vector and so a simple index replace

```
lookup <- setNames(after, before)

for (i in phrase){
  r <- unname(lookup[i])
  print(r)
}
# [1] "A" "B"
# [1] "c" "E"
```

Comment: the for loop can also be replaced by `map(phrase, ~n[.x])` if you like :-)

Comment: or `vapply(phrase, \(x) n[x], character(2L))`

Comment: mention might be made that `map(phrase, ` is `purrr::map(` for clarity.

Comment: Might be even easier to create `myLUT <-  cbind(before, after)`  and just write a loop around   `myLUT[which(phrase[[j]][k] == myLUT[,1]),2]`  (not tested)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft if you post it as an answer I would upvote :-)

Comment: Your solution doesn't work when a string is composed of multiple numbers seperated by a seperator, something like c("1, 11, 2", "1", "22") for example @Mark

Comment: It doesn't work in many contexts Akram, the question is, is it relevant to the actual data?

Comment: If the actual data is different from the example then change the example. You can't blame us if we assume the data is good

Answer (score 1):

To cheer "Mark" up  :-) ,
Might be even easier to create `myLUT <-  cbind(before, after)` and just write a loop around `myLUT[which(phrase[[j]][k] == myLUT[,1]),2]` (not tested)

Comment: :-) :-) :-) :-) :-) :-)

Comment: I tested out `for (j in seq_along(phrase)){
  for (k in seq_along(phrase[[j]])){
    print(myLUT[which(phrase[[j]][k] == myLUT[,1]),2])
  }
}` and it works!