# How to replace old values by new ones in a string where values are separated by a separator?

Tags: r, dplyr, vector, replace, stringi

Here's my code :

```
  V1 = list("1","2","3",c("1,2,3"))
  
  before =  c("1","2","3")
  after = c("2AB","1CD","DC2")
  
   stringi::stri_replace_all_regex(
    V1,
    before, 
    after, 
    vectorize_all = F)
  )
```

What I'm getting is :

```
>  stringi::stri_replace_all_regex(
+     V1,
+     before, 
+     after, 
+     vectorize_all = F)
[1] "1CDAB"         "1CD"           "DC2"           "1CDAB,1CD,DC2"
```

which is not what I'm trying to get which should look like this :

```
"2AB" "1CD" "DC2" "2AB,1CD,DC2"
```

how do I solve this?

Comment: Your regex is finding all instances of "1" and replacing them with "2AB", then replacing all "2"s with "1CD" including the "2"s just inserted by the first replacement.  To amend this, look at setting a regex for a single digit with word breaks either side - from memory (so check) it might be `"\\b1\\b"`

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [Mr. Flick's answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76962582/4145280), but using `str_split()` to split values where necessary:

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse)

# create a named list
d <- setNames(after, before)

# create function
f <- function(x) str_split(x, ",", simplify = TRUE) %>% {d[.]} %>% paste0(collapse = ",")

# apply function to all elements of V1
map_chr(V1, f)
# [1] "2AB"         "1CD"         "DC2"         "2AB,1CD,DC2"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `gsubfn` like below

```
> library(gsubfn)

> relist(gsubfn("\\d+", setNames(as.list(after), before), unlist(V1)), V1)
[[1]]
[1] "2AB"

[[2]]
[1] "1CD"

[[3]]
[1] "DC2"

[[4]]
[1] "2AB,1CD,DC2"
```

---

If you would like to play with base R only, you can try

```
lapply(
    strsplit(unlist(V1), ""),
    \(x) paste0(c(",", after)[match(x, before, nomatch = 0) + 1], collapse = "")
)
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
[1] "2AB"

[[2]]
[1] "1CD"

[[3]]
[1] "DC2"

[[4]]
[1] "2AB,1CD,DC2"
```